# Why does ReactJS render [object Object] instead of array.name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to filter an array of objects based on a boolean value, so it returns new array of objects that only contains objects with "true" value.

here is my base array:

```
const extrasList = [
    {key: 0, name: "extraNew1", price: 20, active: true },
    {key: 1, name: "extraNew2", price: 100, active: false },
    {key: 2, name: "extraNew3", price: 400, active: false },
  ]
```

here is how I used *.filter method* to get only **"active: true"** objects:

```
const activeExtras = extrasList.filter((extra) => {
    return extra.active;
  });
```

and now, to display just names in objects, I used *.map method*:

```
const aExtrasList = activeExtras.map((extra) => {
    return (
      <div key={extra.key}>
        <p>{extra.name} </p>
      </div>
    );
  })
```

I expected React to render "**extraNew1**", but instead I got "**[object Object]**"... what am I missing?

Edit: The code above renders fine, the problem occurs when I try to put it inside of this variable:

```
const toSend = [`name: ${name} - model: ${activeModel} - extra: - ${aExtrasList}`];
```

Note: **name** and **activeModel** are declared in no relation to **aExtrasList**.

Comment: It renders properly for me

Comment: How do you render `aExtraList`?

Comment: You can't put the JSX in a string, but you could do this: `const toSend = <>name: {name} - model: {activeModel} - extra: {aExtrasList}</>`

Comment: aExtrasList is an array and you can not print it

Answer (score -1):

```
const extrasList = [
    {key: 0, name: "extraNew1", price: 20, active: true },
    {key: 1, name: "extraNew2", price: 100, active: false },
    {key: 2, name: "extraNew3", price: 400, active: false },
  ]
  
  const activeExtras = extrasList.filter((extra) => {
    return extra.active;
  });
  
  return(
    <>
      {
      activeExtras.map(extra => {
        return(
          <div key={extra.key}>
            <p>{extra.name} </p>
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: I assume they are doing the same, just that you have put `map` inside the `return` ...